# Redirect from one subdirectory to another, but block direct access to latter subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Like the title implies, I'd like to redirect one subdirectory to another while blocking direct access to the latter subdirectory. For instance, I'd like to block direct access to `domain.com/foo`:

```
RewriteRule ^foo [F,NC]
```

But I want `domain.com/bar` to redirect to `domain.com/foo`:

```
RewriteRule ^bar/* /foo/ [R=301]
```

Is it possible to combine these two rules into one, so `domain.com/bar` will load `domain.com/foo` but `domain.com/foo` will *not* load `domain.com/foo`?

Comment: This question was closed? Textbook example of bored admins with nothing better to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# block direct access to /foo/*
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+foo[/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]

# allow access to /foo/* via /bar/*
RewriteRule ^bar/(.*)$ /foo/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Would you mind quickly explaining how it works?

Comment: sure, 1st rule is using `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable to check if is the actual URL entered in the browser is `/foo/*` if it is then forbidden error is returned to the user. 2nd rule is **internally forwarding** all `/bar/anything` requests to `/foo/anything` URI. Since `R` flag isn't used in 2nd rule therefore `%{THE_REQUEST}` doesn't change and 1st rule isn't fired again. If it answers your problem can you accept this answer now?